# show only object properties from javascript object

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

I have an javascript object returned from c# class library. Object is simple name - value pairs list.

I'm using

```
for (var myList in myListItems) {
  console.log(myList);
  console.log(myListItems[myList]);
}
```

to retrieve all items in list, but next to my items, i'm getting a bunch of .toString methods and several others, probably inherited from something.

Is there a way to remove all this methods, and get only data i need?

Comment: Without seeing more code/context it's hard to say exactly, but a check for [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) would probably help.

Comment: `for...in` will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object and its prototype(s). If you can clearly identify the characteristics of the properties you don't want, then there might be a way to do that. But your current description is incomplete / vague.

Comment: You got a solution, but it's not clear yet why it works. This question isn't really useful until we know the structure of your data and know why `hasOwnProperty` works in this case.

Comment: I have c# method that do some calculations and returns a bunch of name - value pair items to javascript. In javascript i need to print out all that name - value pairs to screen. For some reason, along name - pair values, few .toString methods show up. I guess that's what c# compiler adds to the code... My question was how to remove that .toString methods, .hasOwnProperty worked, i don't know how and why (i'm c# guy with only basic javascript knowledge)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexey is correct about using [Object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Here's an example using your code:

```
for (var myList in myListItems) {
  // Check if myList is a property on myListItems
  if (myListItems.hasOwnProperty(myList)) {
    console.log(myList);
    console.log(myListItems[myList]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to use special JS function Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()

```
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    console.log('this is fog (' + name + ') for sure. Value: ' + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

More info here: [JS Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: Your example would be better if it was a modification of the OP's code, rather than a copy/paste of the MDN article.

Comment: What if `toString` is defined on the object itself?

Comment: @Felix Kling, of course, you are rigth, if toString method is defined on the object itself, toString will be also defined as "internal" property, but as author said, JS objects are returned from C# and I suppose it's just pure JSON objects without any functions.

Comment: *"I suppose it's just pure JSON objects without any functions"* Then why does `toString` show up in the loop? I think the question needs some clarifying.

Comment: @Felix Kling I got it. I missed it. So, in this case at least one extra check should be added: typeof buz[name] === 'function'

Comment: @FelixKling Every object in JS by default has prototype inherited from Object (that's why, probably, toString methods are printed in the example). There is only one case, when it's not - when object is created by Object.create() method with null proto. But I agree with you, that extra info is required for proper answer. Regards, Alex.

Comment: @AlexeySobolev: But all the properties on `Object.prototype` are not enumerable, hence they are not iterated over with `for...in`.